# Why does AWK refuse to sum up floats

Tags: bash, awk, floating-point

I'm facing a rather strange problem with`awk` where I want to calculate the average of a column. This is the test input form my file:

```
1
2
0.4
0.250
0.225
0.221
0.220
0.218
```

And this is the script I'm trying to run:

```
awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum; print sum / NR}' ~/Desktop/bar.txt
```

What I expect as output is:

```
<calculated sum>
<calculated average>
```

But this is what I get invariably:

```
3
0,375
```

I've checked the formatting and characters of the input file etc. but I can't get`awk` to sum up those pesky floats.

Any ideas?

I'm running `awk` version 20070501 in bash 3.2.48 on OS X 10.8.5.

#### Update

As @sudo_O correctly deduced, the problem is my locale. Replacing the `.` with a `,` in the file yields the correct results. That's obviously not the solution I'm looking for though so I need to do something with my locale which is currently set to:

```
$ locale
LANG="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I'd like to keep numeric, monetary and date locales I think. Which locale do I need to change (and how), to make `awk` work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is not `awk` here. Explicitly use floats and see what you get:

```
$ awk '{sum+=sprintf("%f",$1)}END{printf "%.6f\n%.6f\n",sum,sum/NR}' file
4.534000
0.566750
```

It looks like it's probably your locale as your output uses a `,` as the decimal separator so post the output of the `locale` command.

---

So using your `LC_NUMERIC` I can reproduce your results:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC="de_CH.UTF-8" awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum; print sum / NR}' file
3
0,375
```

The fix is to set your `LC_NUMERIC` or `LC_ALL` to `C` or anything else that use `.` as the decimal separator:

```
$ LC_NUMERIC="C" awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum; print sum / NR}' file
4.534
0.56675
```

See `man locale` for more information.

Comment: This is a very useful answer, because it is not entirely obvious that awk fails to produce floating point numbers due to the LC_NUMERIC variable. It is good to recognize how locale affects awk.