# How to set lang env to "en_US.UTF-8" in awk script?

Tags: awk, gawk

I am using `awkc` to generate an executable file from an awk script. I have the following line in an awk script abc.awk:

```
BEGIN{printf "Value=%s\n",(3.13+3.26)}
```

I have generated an executable file (abc.exe), which I have executed on different systems. It gives different outputs in floating point operations.

On one local system it gives the output `6.39` but it gives the output `6` on another system located in a different time zone.

When I searched in various sites I am able to see to set the LANG environmental variable, but how?

Comment: Is this part of an awk script? Should that be `printf`? Can you reproduce the issue with the minimal example `awk 'BEGIN{printf "Value=%s\n",(3.13+3.26)}'`?

Comment: I have explained in brief regarding your suggestion. To add i have generated exe with following command
awkc -o <exe_name> -f <awk_file>

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946689/why-does-awk-refuse-to-sum-up-floats

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this to do with the locale settings on your different systems but if you are looking for a floating-point number, you should use the `"%f"` format specifier. To get an answer to 2 decimal places, use `"%.2f"`:

```
BEGIN{printf "Value=%.2f\n",(3.13+3.26)}
```

This should give the same result, regardless of the system it is run on.

**Edit:** based on the linked question, perhaps you should try using `LC_NUMERIC=C` to explicitly set the locale:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C awk 'BEGIN{printf "Value=%.2f\n",(3.13+3.26)}'
```

should work regardless of the system it is being run on.

Comment: I have tried with "%.2f", but result is "Value=6,00"
I wonder of the comma instead of . in the result. I think there is some dependency with locale. isn't it?

Comment: It is not working since exe is not generating because of wrong format. But i need some solution which is generic to all systems.
Actually my requirement is for a dynamic values which are actually stored in some variables. So by debugging i found problem with floats. So from different sites i found to set locale LC_ALL or LC_NUMERIC to some value which handles numeric expressions. But didn't explain how to use it in script.

Comment: Perhaps you could try `LC_NUMERIC=C abc.exe` on each system?

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how to execute that on command prompt? Should I use some options for it to execute? It is not executing on the command prompt.

Comment: `LC_NUMERIC` is an environment variable. You can set it on the same line when you execute the program (as in my answer), or use `export LC_NUMERIC=C` before running the program.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are typically something that you do not control if you hand a program over to someone else. I would look into being more specific in your `printf`-calls. You can format the numbers into strings in to an astonishing detail. You are probably looking for the `float` (`%f`) (you are now using a `string` (`%s`).

If you notice that you are making always the same trick with your `printf`-calls, you can control the number-to-string conversion settings with a variable `CONVFMT` in a BEGIN-block. I got introduced to this one through `gawk`, apparently it is however in the POSIX standard. Whether `awkc` supports this, I don't know.

From the [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#User_002dmodified):

> This string controls conversion of numbers to strings (see
>   Conversion). It works by being passed, in effect, as the first
>   argument to the sprintf() function (see String Functions). Its default
>   value is "%.6g". CONVFMT was introduced by the POSIX standard.