# Sum up 88 columns based on first one

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like this

```
A  1  3  5
B  2  4  7
C  3  5  9
A  9  0 11
C  7  8  0
```

The file has 88 columns and 100000 lines. I would like to sum up all columns for the rows which have similar first column, like this:

```
A 10  3  16
B  2  4  7
C  10  13  9
```

Usually for two columns only I would use:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]+=$3}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i], b[i]|"sort"}'
```

But now I have 88 columns and I would like to find an easier way to add the rows for all 88 columns without repeating the first part of my awk like (e.g. c[$1]+=$4 ...)

Anyone knows a better/easier way to do it?

Comment: "I would like to sum up all columns for the rows which have similar first column" sounds very vague. Could you give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of awk does not support multi-dimensional array:

```
$ awk '{ idx[$1]++; for (i=1;i<=NF; ++i) { total[$1,i-1] += $i; } } END { for (id in idx) { printf("%s ", id); for(i=1;i<NF;++i) { printf("%d ", total[id,i]); } print "" ; } }' /tmp/sample
A 10 3 16 
B 2 4 7 
C 10 13 9
```

Comment: Thanks, way easier. Do you have a tip on how to handle decimal points? What if I have 10.5 3.8. Because your solution rounds up every number

Comment: Probably your locales, as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946689/why-does-awk-refuse-to-sum-up-floats

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[$1][i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (key in sum) {
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%d%s", sum[key][i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }

}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A 10 3 16
B 2 4 7
C 10 13 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a two-dimensional array, like this:

```
for (col = 2; col <= NF; col++) {
    data[$1, col] += $col;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on awk, here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -lanwe '
    $i=0;
    $k = shift @F;
    $s{$k}[$i++] += $_ for @F;
    END { print "$_ @{ $s{$_} }" for sort keys %s }
' input_file > output_file
```

- `-l` adds a newline to `print`
- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array

The sums are saved in a hash table %s keyed by the first column value.