# bash awk extract and sum values from one numeric col

Tags: bash, awk

I have some data in a file:

```
$ cat data.txt
facture-2817806.txt Total TTC 27.11 €
facture-2857125.txt Total TTC 37.92 €
facture-2895824.txt Total TTC 43.61 €
facture-2922275.txt Total TTC 46.73 €
facture-2935969.txt Total TTC  8.29 €
facture-2977623.txt Total TTC 41.79 €
facture-3005553.txt Total TTC 46.18 €
facture-3020047.txt Total TTC 20.34 €
facture-3061124.txt Total TTC 28.22 €
facture-3097529.txt Total TTC 59.65 €
facture-3258989.txt Total TTC 29.31 €
facture-3637195.txt Total TTC 11.17 €
facture-3681794.txt Total TTC 44.52 €
facture-3726992.txt Total TTC 28.20 €
facture-3752273.txt Total TTC 42.15 €
facture-3770970.txt Total TTC 24.01 €
```

I want to sum float value of one col, I extract the column:

```
$ cat data.txt | awk '{print $4}'
27.11
37.92
43.61
46.73
8.29
41.79
46.18
20.34
28.22
59.65
29.31
11.17
44.52
28.20
42.15
24.01
$
```

What is a good bash way to get the sum of that with one more pipe '|' ?

```
$ cat data.txt | awk '{print $4}' | xxx
```

Note: There a similar issue here: [Why does AWK refuse to sum up floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946689/why-does-awk-refuse-to-sum-up-floats) but in my file float numbers are not alone. 
I look for just an additional liner after the pipe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to sum float value of one col

**The idiomatic way**

```
awk '{count+=$4}END{printf "Total : %f\n",count}' your_file
```

---

**The hard way**

```
awk 'BEGIN{count=0}{count+=$4}END{printf "Total : %f\n",count}' your_file
```

---

As a side note, if you wish to specify the number of digits after the decimal point use something like `%0.2f`.

**Note:** You don't need a pipe at all.

Comment: thank, very elegent, just to understand better why this doesn't work ?:  $ cat data.txt | awk '{print $4}' | awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "Total: %f\n",$s}'
Total: 0.000000

Comment: @user3313834 concerning the question: use **s** not **$s** as argument to printf.

Comment: @LarsFischer : Thanks , just about  to mention this. :-)

Comment: @user3313834: Note `$` usually precedes columns

Answer (score 0):

Possible with `awk`, but in a different way:-

```
awk '{ sum += $4;printf "$%.2f\n",sum}' data.txt
```

it gives sum of $4 in a cumulative way

EDIT:-
To get sum of all the values from column $4 in one shot:-

```
awk '{ sum += $4} END {printf "$%.2f\n",sum}' data.txt
```

Comment: This will print sum in every iteration which might cause perf issue if file is huge.

Comment: @daemon12 - added way to get sum in one go.