# awk rounds floating numbers to integers in math operations on one machine while on other behaves properly

Tags: bash, awk

I have two columns in a file bbb:

2459507.3260843 12.60766

2459507.3266052 12.64228

2459507.3271260 12.66145

A simple awk column printing gives the expected results (the file content as above):
awk '{print $1, $2}' bbb

however trying a math operation on the second column:
awk '{print $1, $2-0.3}' bbb prints this:

2459507.3260843 11,7

2459507.3266052 11,7

2459507.3271260 11,7

It treats the column as integer numbers (12) and prints the coma instead of the dot in decimal numbers on output.

awk '{print $1, $2-1}' bbb prints this:

2459507.3260843 11

2459507.3266052 11

2459507.3271260 11

Is there a global environmental variable responsible for this awk behaviour? I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a new machine (Intel 9, 12 gen. processor). On other computer with ubuntu 20.04 awk behaves properly. I'm not an expert in ubuntu (just a user of the system). I've tried forcing the precision using awk '{printf"%.7f  %.5f\n", $1,$2-1}' bbb  but then I've got:

2459507,0000000  11,00000

2459507,0000000  11,00000

2459507,0000000  11,00000

What happened to awk on my machine?

Thanks

Comment: seems your radix character is different, it should be locale dependent.  Check especially  LC_NUMERIC

Comment: See [Why does AWK refuse to sum up floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18946689)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format the input/output/code blocks in your question (use Code Blocks for all 3).

Comment: Can you provided versions of AWK (output of `awk --version`) for both machines?

Comment: My awk version: awk -W version
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647

Comment: echo $LC_NUMERIC
pl_PL.UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Guys!
karakfa and rowboat have pointed out to locale. I found locale was set to Polish:  LC_NUMERIC=pl_PL.UTF-8

The fix to my awk strange behaviour is shown on the site (above) posted by rowboat (thank you rawboat)

From that site:
"The fix is to set your LC_NUMERIC or LC_ALL to C or anything else that use . as the decimal separator:"
so when I've done this, I've got:

$ LC_NUMERIC="C" awk '{print $1, $2-1}' bbb

2459507.3260843 11.6077

2459507.3266052 11.6423

2459507.3271260 11.6615

as expected.